# UIScrollView that scrolls only programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

We need to make a scroll view that is scrolling only when user swipe at some area on screen, which is NOT inside the scroll view .

So i have created a scroll view that working great ,now i am struggling to find a way to disable the scrolling from within the scroller and somehow read the user swiping in that relevant area(some strip view), and than send that swipes to the scroller, than scroll programmatically with:

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

Is that the right way to achieve this , or there is some out of the box way ?

How would i disable the scrolling option inside the scroller ( **without** disabling touches inside him-because he has some tableView inside), and than just scroll programatically?

**EDIT**  ::

I set the

```
[self.scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
```

than no scrolling enabled.  than when swipe in that view i am trying to move the scroller with:

```
  **[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollXPo+10, y, width, height) animated:YES];**
```

But, its moving the 10 pixels and than its not moving anymore, also the paging is not working in this constellation ..

**EDIT2**

Changed it into :

```
self.scrollView.contentOffset.x+40
```

works, but no paging yet ..

How do i fix this little things ?

Comment: You don't need scroll view to move your content. `UIScrollView` implements the natural user interaction, so if you are going to disable it permanently, just move the frame or bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `UIScrollView`'s `scrollEnabled` to `NO` to disable scrolling by touches, but still keep the possibility to scroll in code. Then you can just use `setContentOffset:animated` to scroll view to the relevant visible area according to you needs (swipine in that relevant area).

As [UIScrollView's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollEnabled) says:

> A Boolean value that determines whether scrolling is enabled.
>   If the value of this property is `YES` , scrolling is enabled, and if it is `NO`, scrolling is disabled. The default is `YES`.
>   When scrolling is disabled, the scroll view does not accept touch events; it forwards them up the responder chain.

Comment: thanks thats what i did exactly but 1. its only moving once and not anymore after this, 2. paging becomes disabled . see my EDIT please.

Comment: 1 is solved, please see edit 2. i have no paging when disabling the touch

Comment: actually what happens is that the scroll view is taking control over the touches ,and when i swipe it gets only one touch and not the swiping action .

Comment: @Curnelious As iMartin pointed out in the comment, you dont need scroll view at all. I believe you cannot achieve both your requirements in a ways as simple as setting property. You can either use scroll view native scroll behavior with paging or you have to implement it completely yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can get view info on touch event, so simply get touched view and check if touched view is scrollview/views with in it, then do not perform scrolling

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        //do not perform programmatically scrolling
    }
    else
   {
       //do your scrolling here
   }
}
```